# How to define type for ref(binding on template) In Vue3, using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Template:

```
<tremplate>
  <div ref="element"></div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  setup() {
    const element = ref(null);
    return {
      element,
    };
  },
};
```

This is a normal way to define a ref in vue3, but in JavaScript way.
And if I'm using TypeScript, I will need to define a type for value `element`, right?

How do I do to ensure the correct type for value `element`?

Answer (score 53):

```html
<template>
   <ChildComponent ref="childRef">
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent.vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'

const childRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof ChildComponent>>()
childRef.value.childMethods()

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: One addition to this, you need to add defineExpose({ childMethods: childMethods}); to ChildComponent while using setup script, in order to be able to access to the method from the ref in the Parent.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you're using `script setup` for ChildComponent.  You get this error: `TS2344: Type '{}' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.`

Answer (score 40):

Well, that would depend on whether or not you need it typed and to provide member information (public properties, methods, etc). If you do, then yes you need to define a type for it; otherwise, you don't have to, and can simply access the unwrapped reference with `.value` which leaves it as type `any` (I bet you figured out this one).

But if you have to, you need to tell the compiler what it **is** or what it's going to be assigned on. To do that, you'll want to use [the third overload of `ref`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/69d5c6887e51687044da25ef671c690d193000d7/packages/reactivity/src/ref.ts#L36) (with no argument) and explicitly set the generic type to the desired type—in your case, you want `HTMLDivElement` (or simply `HTMLElement` if you don't care about the specific members it has to offer).

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const el = ref<HTMLDivElement>();

    onMounted(() => {
      el.value // DIV element
    });

    return {
      el
    }
  }
})
```

In JavaScript, you don't have type checking, so passing `null` on the `ref` function is as good as not passing anything (which is especially okay for template refs)*; it could even come across as being misleading in a sense that the unwrapped value actually resolves to something else *but* `null`.

* When using the Composition API, the concept of "reactive refs" and "template refs" are unified. And the reason we're accessing this particular type of `ref` on the mounted hook is because the DOM element will be assigned to it **after initial render**.

References:

- https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs

Comment: Mind that it is not null, but undefined.
So your type of el in this case would be: Ref<HTMLDivElement | undefined>
Passing null to a function is not the same as just leaving out that parameter (in which case it is undefinded)

Comment: Any idea on how to achieve this when the referenced item is a vue component, not a native DOM element? Is there a way to get the ThisType of the referenced component?

Comment: @coyotte508 Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66909582/3634538) answer your question?

Comment: @YomT. it does!

Answer (score 14):

The line isn't correct:

```
    const el = ref<HTMLDivElement>();
```

The `el` is not an HTMLDivElement. Instead, it's a proxy to the element. The `$el` of that proxy is the actual HTMLDivElement. Though I'm not sure if I get it right. In a component, I managed to type it as follow:

```
import { ComponentPublicInstance, defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  // snipped...
  setup() {
    const field = ref<ComponentPublicInstance<HTMLInputElement>>();
    return {
      field,
      fun() { field.value.$el.value = 'some value'; }
    };
  }
  // snipped...
});
```

Comment: This is wrong for normal div Elements.

For <div ref="test">, use: ref<HTMLDivElement>
For <my-app-component ref="test">, use ref<PublicComponentInstance<MyAppComponent>>

Answer (score 7):

**Vue 3 composition API**

```
<template>
   <input ref="fileInput" style="display: none;" type="file" @change="onFileSelected" />
   <button @click="fileInput?.click()">Pick Files</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const fileInput = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)

function onFileSelected(event: any) { console.log("Event: " + event) }
</script>
```

**Second example**

```
<template>
   <div ref="coolDiv">Some text</div>
   <button @click="changeCoolDiv">Pick Files</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const coolDiv = ref<HTMLDivElement>()

function changeCoolDiv() {
  if(coolDiv) {
    coolDiv.value // Div element
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import { VNodeRef } from 'vue';
```

You can use VNodeRef.

```
const swiperRef = ref<VNodeRef>();
```

Comment: how would the used type be declared? 
like const r = ref<VNodeRef<String | null>>('I am only a String or null');
?

Comment: There are two kinds of refs. DOM ref and reactive ref.VNodeRef is good to use with ref targeting dom element  while for the normal ref use `const name = ref<string | null>(null)`

Answer (score 4):

*From the Vue 3 docs:*

Components using `<script setup>` are closed by default - i.e. the public instance of the component, which is retrieved via template refs or `$parent` chains, will not expose any of the bindings declared inside .

To explicitly expose properties in a  component, use the [defineExpose](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) compiler macro:

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const a = 1
const b = ref(2)

defineExpose({
  a,
  b
})
</script>
```

When a parent gets an instance of this component via template refs, the retrieved instance will be of the shape `{ a: number, b: number }` (refs are automatically unwrapped just like on normal instances).

### Example code

*[From the docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-template-refs):*

Component `MyModal.vue`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'

const isContentShown = ref(false)
const open = () => (isContentShown.value = true)

defineExpose({
  open
})
</script>
```

Parent component `App.vue`:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import MyModal from './MyModal.vue'

const modal = ref<InstanceType<typeof MyModal> | null>(null)

const openModal = () => {
  modal.value?.open()
}
</script>
```

Comment: I would like that only showed the methods that are in the "defineExpose"

Answer (score 1):

If using the `vue-class-component` package (here the beta v8 but the same with `@Component` instead of `@Option` will work in earlier versions):

```
<template>
  <div ref="element">
    <MyOtherComponent ref="otherComponent" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Options, Vue } from 'vue-class-component'
import MyOtherComponent from '../MyOtherComponent.vue'

@Options({
  components: {
    MyOtherComponent,
  },
})

export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  $refs!: {
    element: HTMLDivElement,
    otherComponent: InstanceType<typeof MyOtherComponent>,
  }

  mounted() {
    this.$refs.otherComponent.myOtherComponentMethod()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: exactly whats I was looking for, thx

Comment: How do I do that with the options API?