# What's Vue 3 composition API's type-safe way of defining methods

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm using Vue's composition API (in Vue.js 3) and build my component logic mostly within `setup()`. While [accessing my own props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#props) via `setup(props)` is straight forward, I'm unable to expose the functions defined here as [`methods`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#methods) in a type-safe manner.

The following works, but I need the any-cast, since there's no method interface exposed to TypeScript.

```html
<!-- MyComponent.vue -->

<script lang='ts'>
// ...
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // ...
    return {
       publicFunction: async (): Promise<void> => { /* ... */ };
    }
  }
});

</script>
```

```html
<!-- AppComponent.vue -->

<template>
  <MyComponent ref="my"/>
</template>

<script lang='ts'>

export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    const my = ref();

    async func() {
      await (my.value as any).publicFunction(); // <-- gross!
    }

    return { my, func };
  }
});

</script>
```

Defining my function in `methods` is not an option, since that way, I wouldn't be able to access it from setup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for [`InstanceType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype).

```
import MyComponent from 'path/to/the/component';

export default defineComponent({
  async setup() {
    const my = ref<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>>();

    async func() {
      await my.value?.publicFunction();
    }

    return { my, func };
  }
});
```

One caveat with this approach is that (as you can see) you'd have to use an [optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html) or [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator), unless you pass an initial/default instance as an argument to the `ref()` function; otherwise, TypeScript is going to mark it as "*possibly undefined*".

In most cases, if you are certain that it's always going to be defined, you could type cast it to an empty object with the [`as`-syntax](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
const my = ref({} as InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>);

async func() {
  await my.value.publicFunction();
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! Unfortunately this is mentioned nowhere in the official Vue.js docs.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but I am using SFC in vue3 with Typescript so any suggestion for that? I guess in SFC method is not public