# Typing Component Ref in Vue results in TS2344 error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, typescript-typings

I got a component ref on my component FormCheckbox from a patternlib. I tried to type the component in my own component TestComp but I get this ts error and I don't understand why:
`TS2344: Type '{ name: string; mixins: any[]; inheritAttrs: boolean; props: { id: { type: StringConstructor; required: boolean; }; label: { type: StringConstructor; default: string; }; checked: { ...; }; disabled: { ...; }; }; emits: string[]; computed: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint 'new (...args: any) => any'.   Type '{ name: string; mixins: any[]; inheritAttrs: boolean; props: { id: { type: StringConstructor; required: boolean; }; label: { type: StringConstructor; default: string; }; checked: { ...; }; disabled: { ...; }; }; emits: string[]; computed: { ...; }; }' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.`

FormCheckbox
...

```
<script>
import spacingMixin from "../mixins/spacing.js";

export default {
  name: "FormCheckbox",
  mixins: [
    spacingMixin
  ],
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    },
    checked: {
      type: Boolean
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  emits: ["update:checked"],
  computed: {
    fieldAttributes() {
      const { ...attrs } = this.$attrs;
      delete attrs['class']
      return attrs;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

...

TestComp
...

```
<template>
<FormCheckbox id="SelectAll" ref="selectAllCheckbox"/>
</template>
export default defineComponent({
    name: "TestComp",
    components: {
        FormCheckbox,
    },
    setup() {
      const checkbox: Ref<InstanceType<typeof FormCheckbox> | null> = ref(null);
      return {checkbox}
    },
});
</script>
```

...

I tried to add a InstanceType to my ref because I want to use the $el property later on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define type for ref(binding on template) In Vue3, using TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002098/how-to-define-type-for-refbinding-on-template-in-vue3-using-typescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a

```
export default /* FormCheckbox */ { ... }
```

```
import FormCheckbox from ...
export default /* TestComp */ defineComponent({ ... })
```

Buuuut... `defineComponent` expects your inported component to be a `Component` returned by `defineComponent`. It won't allow you to use object.

What you need is to fix `FormCheckbox` to also use `defineComponent`

---

If you don't have access to code, you may use

```
// shims-vue.d.ts

/// <reference types="vite/client" />
/// <reference types="vue/ref-macros" />

// Mocks all files ending in `.vue` showing them as plain Vue instances
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'

  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

or

```
import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
let myRef = Ref<DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>>(/* implied `undefined` */)
```

or use `this.$refs.selectAllCheckbox` then you don't need to define it at all iirc

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem I have now is that the Component is not from me so I can't change it. Is is still possible to get the correct typing without changing the component?